# run a bash command and redirect stdout/stderr to different files each limited to 50K

Tags: bash, redirect, truncate

I can do it without the file size limit:

`bash_script >${TMP}/stdout 2>${TMP}/stderr`

I could just truncate them afterwards, but what I want is for them never to get bigger than the size limit in the first place...

Comment: Have you tried `ulimit -f 50`?

Comment: Would this constrain all files or just the output of stdout/stderr?
It's just those I want to limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `head -c50kB` to limit a pipe to its first 50'000 bytes.

```
bash_script > >(head -c50kB > "$tmp/stdout") 2> >(head -c50kB > "$tmp/stderr")
```

or

```
bash_script 2> >(head -c50kB > "$tmp/stderr") | head -c50kB > "$tmp/stdout"
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Are there any important differences between these two ways (if so what are they) that make one preferrable?

Comment: I don't think there are any noticeable differences apart from readability. Choose the one that looks best to you.

Comment: This worked fine when the head limit acted to truncate excess bytes. However it caused some problems when head never got to the limit; some bytes seemed to get stuck in the pipe and never get flushed out. In particular in a test where the bash_script is doing a small printf.

Comment: That's good to know and somewhat odd. Maybe you can solve the problem by adding `stdbuf -i0` in front of every `head`. I cannot try at the moment.

Comment: Yes I tried stdbuf. For now I'm truncating after redirecting. It's not at all urgent. Maybe this is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461014

Comment: The linked question answers problems about the cases where a limit was reached. However, you said that you had problems when the limit was *not* reached. This puzzles me and I could not reproduce this problem so far. Can you reproduce the problem, boil it down to a small script, and post that script here?

Comment: My response is longer than allowed for this comment. I've put it into a gist. https://gist.github.com/JonJagger/70ddb173b177c767c10098865160e112

Comment: At first glance it seems like a buffering issue. When you kill your script, buffered data is lost. In that case `stdbuf` should have solved the issue. However, from your gist and comments it is still not clear what exactly you do (for instance, I don't know whether you kill only the c program or the whole shell. Also, I do not know where you placed `stdbuf`). Could you please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You can edit that example to your question by editing.

Comment: I kill the container (SIGTERM, 2 seconds wait, then SIGKILL). It has an pid-1 init process. That kills my main.sh; main.sh was running cyber-dojo.sh; cyber-dojo.sh was compiling and running the C program. I can add setbuf to main.sh but I don't think that will affect cyber-dojo.sh (which it runs) since that has its own stdout/stderr? If I get time I will try to create an expanded gist.

Comment: If you do so, please mind the *"minimal"* in [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Especially dependencies like dojo are probably not necessary to reproduce the problem.